# Can a DFA have an empty string as input?

Tags: finite-automata

Given string w such that every odd position in w is a 1

My solution is

[image: sol1]

The book's solution is

[image: sol2]

from my understanding $\epsilon$ should not be an accepted state, however in the book's solution it is. How is it handling this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, an empty string is a valid input to a DFA. If this were not the case, DFAs would not be closed under all of the Kleene algebra operations.

In this case, the argument is correct. Think of the problem statement as an implication. If $i$ is an odd position, then $S_i$ is 1.

Comment: then does that mean the book's answer is wrong?

Comment: @Edqu3 : ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ No. ​ ​ ​ See ​ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth . ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky Demer  by that logic the string { } has a 1 in every odd position.

Comment: @Edqu3 : ​ Exactly. ​ ​ ​ ​